# Export .ai logo for InDesign? Type rendering pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, file-format, file-placing

I have a logo in Illustrator that I inherited, I'm just trying to put it into an InDesign file but for some foresaken reason the text always comes out pixelated. (See attached screenshot)

I've tried "create outlines" for the text, saving and importing in .pdf, .tiff, .svg, .eps, .ai - you name it but cannot for the life of me get the text to render smoothly.

The artboard is about 1000px x 1000px and it only needs to be about 2 inches big in the InDesign document.

Raster effect settings are 300dpi.

Any suggestions appreciated!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is the logo a vector inside of the Illustrator file? Sometimes when I get an AI or EPS file from a client it is just an image embedded.

Comment: It was initially made in InDesign but it's just some rectangles and letters so I re-did it in Illustrator but still having these rendering issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within InDesign, change your view settings.

View menu > Display Performance > High Quality Display.

[image]